# Module Not Found Error in Python 3.6 on windows command prompt

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I have created a project like the below one:

```
project
|
| --package1
|      |
|      -- __init__py
|      --module1.py
|
| --package2
       |
       --__init__.py
       --module2.py
```

I want to import module1 into module2, (from package1 import module1)

In PyCharm everything is just working fine. But when I try to open the file "module2.py" from Windows10 command prompt I get  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module1'`.

I was looking for the solution but not a single one worked.
I'm using python 3.6 and I have set environment variable `PYTHONPATH = I:\project\package1`

Comment: Are module1.py and module2.py in the same folder?

Comment: module1 is in the package1 and module2 is in the package2

Comment: and both package1 and package2 are in the project folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, python only searches current directory. So you'll need to append the path a bit.

In module 2:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\PathTo\project\package1')
import module1
```

That should fix the issue you were having.

Comment: Late to the show here, but I used this tactic and i tworked for the top level import... but then my import has imports, and I get the same error for the deeper import. Is there no way to solve this in general?