# Lots of trouble running a python script from the command line

Tags: python, command-line-interface

**Context for how you answer:** I am new to the command line environment, except when it comes to basic git commands. I've always just used an IDE like PyCharm or NetBeans to run stuff for school projects. Please frame your answer accordingly.

I have a very small python script that pulls down a URL:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\WNeill\PycharmProjects\bloomskyGrantGrove\venv\Lib\site-packages\bloomsky_api')
import bloomsky_api as bs

client = bs.BloomSkyAPIClient(api_key='pr-XXXXXXXXXX')
data = client.get_data()[0] # Dictionary formatted like JSON, if you want data besides the latest image

with open("image_URL.txt", 'w') as file:
    print(data.get('outdoor').get('image_url'), file=file)
```

I did the `sys.path.append()` because I read in a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50527401/module-not-found-error-in-python-3-6-on-windows-command-prompt) that it would solve my problems of "module not found" when running my scripts from the command line.

Well, it did, sort of... now, it finds my imports, but apparently my imports have imports...

`$ py -m bloomtest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\WNeill\PycharmProjects\bloomskyGrantGrove\bloomtest.py", line 4, in <module>
    import bloomsky_api as bs
  File "C:\Users\WNeill\PycharmProjects\bloomskyGrantGrove\venv\Lib\site-packages\bloomsky_api\bloomsky_api.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'`

So what do I do to make this work when my dependencies have dependencies?

Comment: You are using a reference to virtual env. I hope those modules are also present in the same environment or no? Post the error as well you are getting

Comment: I have no idea. I know little about what goes on behind the curtain, as I have only ever used an IDE that takes care of everything for me. Hence the contextual info at the top of my question.

Comment: I'd recommend learning about python virtual environments. It should solve your problem. To me, your problem is not very clear but I believe if you install everything in the global package first and then create the virtual env for your application and install necessary modules specific to your application it should solve the problem. With the little context provided, I cannot help more

Comment: is requests module present. can you do `pip freeze | grep requests` equivalent in windows

Comment: @mad_ I'll look into it. Conceptually, I know the purpose of virtual environments is to keep project dependencies separate, in case on or more rely on different versions of the same libraries. I'll have to dig deeper. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I think @mad_ had the right idea, you should just use virtual environments. What OS are you using?

Comment: @mad_ I am using git bash, so I think `pip freeze | grep requests` should work, however it does not in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `sys.path.append`. Imagine sending your code to someone else, their packages won't be in the same path and they won't be able to run your program. You might not plan on distributing your code but it's just bad practice.

Instead you should use `pip` to install your packages, as i assume you've been using the PyCharm package manager. I think it automatically installs with current versions of python (not sure though, I'm on Linux) and it's used like so:

```
pip install BloomSky-API
```

it'll automatically get all the dependencies and put them in the right places.

I've never used the `py` command before (am I missing out?), try using `python bloomtest.py` to run it instead just to be sure. You might get an error telling you that `python` is an unrecognized command or file, if that's the case it means your PATH is not set up correctly. I've found the easiest way to resolve this is to simply reinstall python, making sure to check the checkbox that says to add python to your PATH.

I'd usually post suggestions like this in a comment if I'm not sure if it solves the problem you're having, but the answer is too long to fit in a comment. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, and thank you! I actually almost always use pip to install my packages (PyCharm has a little terminal window, where I have embedded Git Bash and use it to do `pip install`). Using pip is one of the few commands I know besides git commands... And it's easier than going into my project settings and navigating through all the menus to install a new library. Sometimes pip throws errors, and then I use PyCharm, but not in this case.

As to the `py` command, using `python` or `py` causes the same error.

Comment: Hey! So I found the issue, (I don't know why it is an issue?), but when I run `pip install BloomSky-API` from the embedded command line in PyCharm, it says `requirement already satisfied: BloomSky-API`. I decided to open up my Git Bash terminal window seperately, like I have to do when I'm working in NetBeans and try it there... And it installed the API as if I had never done it... And then everything worked fine! Any clue what happened there?

Answer (score 1):

I want to post the final solution to my problem, which I stumbled on thanks to **DutChen18**'s answer.

He said I should use `pip install` to install all of my packages, which is one thing that I already do. I don't know much about the command line, except basic git and that. Trying to do it again gave me `requirement already satisfied` errors.

However, I was using an embedded terminal in PyCharm: `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe`, which comes when you download Git. This works great in PyCharm because it automatically starts in the working directory of your project. Very convenient for me, a new command line user.

I decided to open up Git Bash separately from PyCharm and run `pip install` again. The first thing I found is that it didn't work without `python -m pip install`, unlike in the PyCharm embedded terminal.

Once I figured that out, I tried to `python -m pip install BloomSky-API`, but this time it didn't tell me that the libraries were already installed. All of a sudden, I could run my python script from the command line.

I have **ZERO** clue as to why this happened or why it now works, and I would love to hear a more technical explanation now that I have things working.